# Display maps without Google Key API

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I'm using this jQuery plugin: http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html to display maps with `Latitude` and  `Longitude`

I ask If there is another solution without using a Key from Google Maps API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API v3 does not require an API key, so if all else fails, start with a Google search for a jQuery plugin that is compatible with Maps API v3.

(It probably won't work, but you can also try changing `http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=API_KEY` to `http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3` while following the installation instructions for the plugin you have selected.)

It should be noted that the API keys are free and that it is a fast and easy process to get them.  So you can also consider just getting one.